# Combining a user defined literal with a method call

Tags: c++, c++11, user-defined-literals

I'm wondering why I can't write code like this:

```
constexpr double radius = 27_km.to_miles(); // _km returns Distance instance 
                                            // which has to_miles()
```

Both GCC 4.8.1 and Clang 3.4 complain that they couldn't find literal operator `operator"" _km.to_miles` unless I wrap `27_km` in parentheses:

```
constexpr double radius = (27_km).to_miles(); // fine
```

By my reading of section 2.14.8 of the standard, a UDL suffix can't contain a period, so why are the compilers parsing the code like this? Are they correct or is it a bug?

EDIT: You can see a full example (with different UDL and method names) here: http://ideone.com/rvB1pk

Comment: I didn't even know this feature of C++11, thanks!

Comment: Could you show a full example that produces the error?

Comment: I've added a link to an example.

Comment: This version compiles on clang++3.4: `30_au .to_light_years();` (note the whitespace) -- which is.. strange.

Comment: @DyP: same thing with GCC 4.8.1. You can insert spaces like that after a variable name too, so it isn't that strange.

Comment: I didn't mean it is strange inserting a whitespace makes it work (I suspected it would work, tried, and succeeded), but it is strange that there's a difference between `30_au.to_light_years()` and `30_au .to_light_years()` [with a whitespace]. I agree with Jerry Coffin's analysis that it's probably a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be a lexer issue.  The user-defined literal is to be tokenized as a single chunk - number plus suffix is one whole token.  In the case of numeric literals the characters it is allowed to slurp up includes the decimal '.'.  Lookup pp-number: section 2.10 - lex.ppnumber in the [latest draft](http://isocpp.org/files/papers/N3797.pdf) of the standard.  Walk through how the preprocessor (lexer) would scan the token:

```
30_au.to_light_years()

digit
digit
identifier-nondigit
.
identifier-nondigit x 14
( breaks the spell
```

So the *preprocessor* sees `30_au.to_light_years` as a big freaky (floating-point) number.  Then *later*, during the number parsing phase we see `digit, digit, identifier-nondigit...`  At that point, the remainder from '-' onwards is handed off as a suffix identifier.

Remember that number literals are interpreted *after* the preprocessor tokenizes.

I think this is actually *not* a defect.

Comment: After looking at section 2.10 I agree - it doesn't look like a defect, although it is an inconvenience!

Comment: @AlexKorban: After looking at §2.2/7, I disagree. "The process of analyzing and translating the tokens may occasionally result in one token being replaced by a sequence of other tokens". Starting as a single preprocessor token doesn't mean it stays a single token throughout compilation.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: that note specifically refers to 14.2 ("Names of template specializations"), which appears to be about the disambiguation of >>. So it seems to me emsr's interpretation is still correct. Am I missing something?

Comment: @AlexKorban: Yes, I think so -- that's giving a reference to one possibility, but does nothing to limit it to that one possibility.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: I guess it could be interpreted like that. I hope you're correct, as it would mean there's a possibility I won't have to wrap literals in parentheses in the future!

Answer (score 3):

The suffix for a UDL is supposed to be a normal identifier (with a leading underscore), so it looks like a bug to me.